# Passing in string of integers to a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procs and mySQL in general, i am calling the sp with

```
    String ids = "1,2,3,4,5";
    CallableStatement proc = 
        connection.prepareCall("{ call p_test(?) }");
    proc.setString(1, ids);
    cs.execute();



    CREATE PROCEDURE test.`p_test`(IN ids String)
    ...
    SELECT  * 
    FROM  table1 t1
    WHERE t1.int_field IN (ids)
    ...
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql doesn't have an array type that you can pass to a stored procedure. What you're passing is just a string and will only match if `t1.int_field in ("1,2,3,4,5,6")`, a single string. What you want is `t1.int_field in (1,2,3,4,5,6)`, a list of integers.

The general approach is to:

1. Have your stored procedure create a temporary table to hold the individual integer values
2. Use Mysql string functions within a loop to break up the string "1,2,3,4,5,6" and insert each value into the temporary table.
3. Use the temporary table containing the values in your query. Your WHERE clause would become something like `WHERE t1.int_field in (select ID from my_temp_table)`

Comment: Except it wouldn't work. id REGEXP '1|2|3' will match a lot more records than just id=1, id=2, and id=3. It will match id=21, id=11, id=14, id=100, etc

Comment: ahhh you're correct. In that case I'd forego the temp table and create a function that splits the string instead. Something like 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM  table1 t1
    WHERE t1.int_field IN (SELECT id FROM split_function(ids,','). The function would be similar to your item 2

Comment: Is there an example for String function?